# Difference between starvation, livelock, deadlock

Tags: multithreading, deadlock, starvation, livelock

Is this table a correct way to summarize difference between starvation, livelock and deadlock?
Mainly I am asking about "thread is active", "how many threads", "nr of resources / locks" columns correctness

|  | thread is active | how many threads | nr of resources / locks | summary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **starvation** | yes | 1 | 1 | the thread is preceded by other threads in accessing the resource/lock |
| livelock | yes | 2 | 2 | scenario like in deadlock, but the threads are actively running and freeing resources and trying to allocate them in reverse order, but the blocking situation repeats, etc. |
| **deadlock** | no | 2 | 2 | Two threads claim two resources/locks but in reverse order. They immediately block both resources/locks and thus block each other |

Comment: No. 1. You can't have starvation with only one thread. 2. See (3). 3. Deadlock can involve a circular chain of *N* threads or processes where *N > 1*. Two is just a special case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column "Thread is active". If we open [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/starvelive.html), we'll see that in all the cases a thread "is unable to make progress". So it's rather optimistic to call the starvation or livelocked threads as active. It's better to say that the state is blocked in deadlock case, and is not blocked in starvation and livelock, but unable to make progress.
Column "How many threads". Deadlock and Livelock can block not only the 2 threads, but 2 and more, because thare are cases when threads block each other not directly, but in a
[circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Znre7.png). Screenshot from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cgZbACBpxI&list=PLL8woMHwr36EDxjUoCzboZjedsnhLP1j4&index=17&ab_channel=JakobJenkov).